# Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException") returns null

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to get a type reference to `System.Net.WebException` from its name by doing the following:

```cs
var t = Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException");
```

`t` is `null` which I don't understand why. My project is a class library targeting .NET 4.6.1. I am referencing `System` and also tried referencing `System.Net` and `System.Web` without any luck.

The following compiles and returns the correct type:

```cs
var t = typeof(System.Net.WebException);
```

But I need the `string` version to work here. I also tried this:

```cs
var t = Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException, System");
```

Returns `null` as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) of `Type.GetType`, you can only pass a namespace-qualified type name if the type is in mscorlib.dll, otherwise you have to use the assembly-qualified name. [`WebException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.8) is not in mscorlib.dll, so you at least need:

```
Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0")
```

By inspecting `typeof(WebException).AssemblyQualifiedName`, you can see that is something like:

```
System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use this:

```
var t = Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException" + ", System");
```

Have you tried the following:

```
 var t = Type.GetType("System.Net.WebException", true);
```

You would have taken the following error message:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'System.Net.WebException' from assembly 'ConsoleApp1, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   ......

The second argument we pass, `true`, indicates that we want this method call to throw an error if the type is not found. So by passing this, you will notice that `Type.GetType` expects the fully qualified name. More formally as it is stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetType):

```
public static Type GetType (string typeName);
```

Parameters

```
typeName String
```

The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. **If** the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Comment: You answer is correct. I have accepted the other answer since it's more precise (IMO). I tried `"System.Net.WebException" + ", System"` (last part of my question). Good point with adding the `throwOnError` boolean.

Comment: @ThomasArdal Not a problem at all :) and no need to explain you choice :). Thanks !